# Prompt only when closing browser not when clicking save button or when navigating away from page using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to prompt when user typed something in the textbox and unknowingly close the browser?

Also if the user doesn't type anything in the input field and if close the browser, the browser should close without prompting. Browser should prompt only if the user changed something in the field. If I use `onbeforeunload` event, it promts for everything even when saving the page. Is there any way to solve my problem in javascript. Please help by giving me apt codes.

Comment: excellent first question, what have you tried?

Comment: You can use an `onchange` handler to set a flag saying that he's changed something. The `submit` handler can clear the flag, and the `onbeforeunload` handler can check it to decide whether to warn.

Comment: I tried:                                                                                                                                         `var needToConfirm = true;
  
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (needToConfirm)
      return "";
  }`   This one prompts for everything as said above.Navigation prompt says "Are u want to leave" in IE,Chrome whereas In Firefox,it says "do u want to leave -your values wont be saved" even when clicking save button.Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134123/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml

It gives you information on how to handle onbeforeunload event.

The idea is to have a global flag on the page. When any change is done to the fields, this flag is set to true. When clicked on save button, then this flag needs to be set to false.

In the onbeforeunload event, check whether the flag is true, then show the message accordingly.

```
var needToConfirm = true;

window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    if (needToConfirm)
    {
        // check on the elements whether any change has been done on the fields.
        // If any change has been done, then set message here.
    }
}

function saveClicked()
{
    needToConfirm = false;
}
```

Another way of doing the things, would be to set the needToConfirm flag when any change is made to the fields via onchange events.

Comment: I already tried this.I like the way they used for `step2` and `step3`.But I am not sure how to apply in mine.I already have validate function and i have `onclick` for that function in `Save` button.when using step2 in mine without using onclick in save button,I am getting prompts for everything.But I am not clear how to use step3 in mine,since I have only one text box and I have to check that alone.`SAYING CLEARLY` `If I haven't enter anything in text box and if I click save button or when closing browser"IT SHOULDN'T PROMPT".It should prompt only when entering something and exiting browser`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload` . 
You can check if the user has entered any text, and if yes, you simply return the message that you want to prompted.

```
var hook = false; //

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var x = $('#box').val();
    if (x.length > 1) { //check is user has entered text
        hook = true;
    }

    if (hook) { //return message if there is text
        hook = false; //reset hook
        return "Did you save your work?"
    }
}​
```

[Read more about window.onbeforeunload here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload)

[Here is a link to a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9VkMh/14/)

Comment: k.As per your concept,if I use your 'href' as my save button,when clicking it says "Are u want to leave" in IE and Chrome,and in firefox it says "do u want to leave -your values wont be saved".It wasn't right.Can U get something related.Please....

Comment: The anchor tag (I believe this is the tag you reffed to as 'href') was placed in the demo for demonstration purposes. I guess you are having a problem because you dont set the `hook` variable back to `false` when your save button is clicked.

Comment: You have a point, in your case this prompt will appear every time if there is text in the text box even if it has been saved. One solution would be to use another condition that checks if the user clicked 'save', before the condition that checks if there is text in the text box.